# How to set column DEFAULT using value of a variable

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, default-value

In a script for setting up a database which uses random UUIDs for primary keys, I have:

```
CREATE TABLE alpha (id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), value INT);
CREATE TABLE beta (aref UUID REFERENCES alpha (id));

INSERT INTO alpha (value) VALUES (42);
```

Then over a foreign key, to have that record in "alpha" be the default target for insertions into the "beta" table table:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE l_id UUID;
    BEGIN
        SELECT alpha.id FROM alpha INTO l_id;
        ALTER TABLE beta ALTER COLUMN aref SET DEFAULT l_id;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  column "l_id" does not exist
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "ALTER TABLE beta ALTER COLUMN aref SET DEFAULT l_id"
> PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 1 at SQL statement
> ```

How do I use the value of a variable as the default value for a column?

Comment: Does this all mean that your default keeps changing?  If so, I would not set the default but use a subquery in the insertion statement to obtain the value.

Comment: The value won't change, but is not known when writing the script.  I could probably hardcode a pre-generated UUID instead of relying on the automatically generated one, but I'm wondering if there is a solution to this problem for future reference.

Comment: `execute format('ALTER TABLE beta ALTER COLUMN aref SET DEFAULT %L::uuid', l_id);`

Comment: @Abelisto: you should add that as an answer

Comment: I was hoping for something cleaner than an `eval`-style answer, but I'm happy to accept that as the answer though if you post it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to assume ***variable substitution*** for an SQL utility command like `ALTER TABLE`, but that's not implemented.

Also not possible to ***pass values*** for utility commands to `EXECUTE` with the `USING` clause in plpgsql.
Detailed explanation for both in this related answer on SO:

- [Error when setting n_distinct using a plpgsql variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36025963/939860)

Concatenate the statement, then execute it - like [@Abelisto hinted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144818/how-to-set-default-using-value-of-a-variable-postgres#comment274787_144818). But you don't *need* a variable, you can concatenate the lookup value directly:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE beta ALTER COLUMN aref SET DEFAULT %L'
             , (SELECT a.id::text FROM alpha a));
END $$;
```

The `SELECT` must return a single value.
I cast to `text` explicitly, which is not strictly necessary. Casting the string literal to the target type `uuid` isn't required, either. Postgres will derive that from the column type automatically.

Related:

- [CREATE SEQUENCE using expressions with psql variables for parameters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139681/create-sequence-using-expressions-with-psql-variables-for-parameters/139811#139811)