# Is it possible to write a function in postgresql which directly writes its parameters to a text file?

Tags: postgresql, functions

I have a text file which contains some rows of data,say 10 rows. Each row has 5 columns, each of the type varchar. Is it possible to write a function in postgresql, which takes its parameters as 5 varchar values, and appends those values to that file directly?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html), this boils down to one simple SQL command:

```
COPY (SELECT 'a','b','c','d','e') TO PROGRAM 'cat >> /path/to/file/my.csv';
```

You can wrap it into a function if required:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_dump_row(varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar)
  RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format($$COPY (SELECT %L,%L,%L,%L,%L) TO PROGRAM 'cat >> /path/to/file/my.csv'$$
             , $1,$2,$3,$4,$5); 
END
$func$;
```

Why the complication with `EXECUTE`?

- [How to set column DEFAULT using value of a variable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144818/how-to-set-column-default-using-value-of-a-variable/144859#144859)

[`cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) is a standard UNIX utility (shell command).

Your Postgres role needs appropriate privileges. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.8)

> `COPY` naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers
>   or users who are granted one of the default roles
>   `pg_read_server_files`, `pg_write_server_files`, or
>   `pg_execute_server_program`, since it allows reading or writing any file
>   or running a program that the server has privileges to access.

If you need this for under-privileged roles, consider a [`SECURITY DEFINER` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY). But do it properly as instructed in the manual to avoid misuse.

And the target file must be writable by the system user running the Postgres process, typically `postgres`.

Related:

- [copy command in postgresql to append data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149745/copy-command-in-postgresql-to-append-data)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."AddFiveValues"(
    text1 TEXT,
    text2 TEXT,
    text3 TEXT,
    text4 TEXT,
    text5 TEXT)
    RETURNS TEXT
    LANGUAGE 'sql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
CREATE TEMP TABLE mytable AS
   SELECT  $1 as text1,$2 as text2,$3 as text3,$4 as text4,$5 as text5;
COPY mytable TO PROGRAM '/tmp/append'; 
DROP TABLE mytable;
SELECT '1';
$BODY$;
```

Also you need a script '/tmp/append' (which is executable by 'postgres'):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
        echo $line >> /tmp/results.txt
done
```

`SELECT public."AddFiveValues"( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5');` will add one line to '/tmp/results.txt'.

Filename(s) can (or should?) be changed as needed....

Comment: `select $1 as text1`  can be simplified to `select text1` You don't need the temp table either

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: True, but my question than is: What use is it to add these values to a textfile? Would it not be smarter to add them to a database table, and export them as they are needed?

Comment: @Luuk The reason I am directly adding these values to a text file is that my text file contains some comments(starting with #), in between some rows of data. Hence, I am not able to store all data of the file in a table, as comments can't be stored in that table. That is why I wanted to append the next row of data directly to the file.

Comment: @suvrat: why don't you simply add a column to the table that stores the comment?