# How to create comment on table from query result

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, psql

I want to use a query result as comment on the table. I have tried in psql:

```
\set list select count(*) from department.master_data
COMMENT ON TABLE department.master_data IS :list;
```

But I got this error:

```
it=> \set list select count(*) from department.master_data
it=> COMMENT ON TABLE department.master_data IS :list;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "selectcount"
LINE 1: ...ABLE department.master_data IS selectcoun...
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Maybe you should tell us what the real, underlying problem is that you are trying to solve with that.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not sure what you want to achieve (why it makes sense to store a count as a comment, especially if your table will get new rows (or lose some to `DELETE`s)), but here is how what your problem is and how you can solve it.

First, check what `psql` thinks you have in the variable:

```
\echo :list
selectcount(*)fromdepartment.master_data
```

Clearly not the *result* of your query.  To store that, you'll have to use [`\gset`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-psql.html):

```
> SELECT count(*) AS master_data_count FROM department.master_data;
 master_data_count
───────────────────
        1234567890
(1 row)

> \gset
> \echo :master_data_count
1234567890
```

If you would try to set the table description now, you'd get another error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1234567890"
LINE 1: ...ABLE department.master_data IS selectcoun...
```

This is because the comment must be a (quote-delimited) text.  To get one out of your variable, you have two options.  One is adding escaped quotes to the variable using `psql` (using the same feature you misused setting `:list`:

```
> \set master_data_count '\'' :master_data_count '\''
> \echo :master_data_count
'1234567890'
```

Or you can add the quote already in your query, so `SELECT count(*)` turns into

```
SELECT $$'$$ || count(*) || $$'$$
```

(I used [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) above to avoid typing things like `''''`.)

The result you can already use as a comment, as it contains the necessary quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\gset` in psql to store the result of a query in a local variable - like dezso already advised. Shorter yet, `\gset` can replace the semicolon (`;`) as query terminator:

```
test=# SELECT count(*) AS list FROM department.master_data \gset
```

Then, to get a single-quoted string (with any contained single quotes safely escaped automatically)  refer to the psql variable with this syntax variant: **`:'list'`**. Note the enclosing **`''`** *after* the colon!

```
test=# COMMENT ON TABLE department.master_data IS :'list';
```

Read about [SQL interpolation in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION).

Related:

- [CREATE SEQUENCE using expressions with psql variables for parameters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139681/create-sequence-using-expressions-with-psql-variables-for-parameters/139811#139811)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html), the `:list` part should be enclosed in quotation marks:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE  department.master_data
    IS ':list';
```

Comment: Have you tried the outcome of this?